# ¿Cómo se puede instalar una versión antigua de composer?

Tags: php, composer

Quiero instalar una versión antigua de composer, pero aun no se como. Me aparece la opción de descargar un archivo e importarlo y ejecutarlo cada que quiera usar composer, pero lo que busco es instalarlo en toda mi pc.
La opción que encontré era descargar el archivo **composer.phar** y ejecutarlo cada vez con
`php \composer.phar` (previamente ponerlo en la carpeta del proyecto), lo que yo busco es instalarlo en toda la pc sin tener que ejecutar ese comando sino solo `composer install` tipo así.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la pagina de Composer justo en el área de [descargas](https://getcomposer.org/download/) (has un poco de scroll)

Tienes el listado de versiones,  descarga la que necesitas. no olvides desinstalar la versión actual

También tienes la [repo oficial en github](https://github.com/composer/windows-setup)

Solo debes navegar entre los commits para  encontrar la versión que buscas.

Comment: Muchas gracias! si me funciono